# DomainService Include() Method Not Returning Children To Silverlight Client

Tags: silverlight, .net-3.5, service, dns

This is driving me mad, I've got a DomainService call which on the server contains an Include() to return child objects as follows:

```
public IQueryable<RegionBorder> GetRegionBordersWithPolygonsAndLatLongs()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.RegionBorders.Include("RegionPolygons.LatLongs");
    }
```

I've set this line as a debug point on the server and it is generating the correct results with the child collections included within the toplevel entities. However, on the client, I cannot access the children. The client code is as follows:

```
EntityQuery<RegionBorder> query = idc.GetRegionBordersWithPolygonsAndLatLongsQuery();
        LoadOperation<RegionBorder> lo = idc.Load<RegionBorder>(query);
        lo.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e1)
        {
            //regionBorders = idc.RegionBorders;
            string prtyName = "ProjOverspend";
            var elements = new Collection<FrameworkElement>();
            var propertySet = new ExtendedPropertySet();
            propertySet.RegisterProperty(prtyName, prtyName, typeof(double), 0d);

            foreach (RegionBorder ent in idc.RegionBorders)
            {
                foreach (RegionPolygon rp in ent.RegionPolygons)
                {
                    Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.MapPolygon mp = new Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map.MapPolygon();
                    mp.Points = rp.Points;
                    elements.Add(mp);
                    SetExtendedProperty(propertySet, prtyName, mp, 0d);
                }
            }
```

Can anybody help me with where I am going wrong because I am sure this was working fine before and now just will not do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Martyn.

Comment: Are these spatial types?  They are currently not supported by WCF RIA Services. http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/153739/343126.aspx

Comment: Originally they were spatial types, however, I've altered the database to store a table of polygons that make up each region and then another table that stores all the individual Latitude/Longitude points of each polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add IncludeAttribute in metadata as well.

Comment: Thank you, my metadata class was screwed up and when I re-created the Domain Service after adding some new entities, the metadata hadn't regenerated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way of making the Domain Service Dialog in VS2010, which generates the metadata, automatically add the [Include] and [Association("[String name]", "[String thisKey]", "[String otherKey]")] tags?

It is quite a bit of work to maintain and test if you, for some reason, need to regenerate the Domain Service, if you eg. implemented many/major changes in the Entity Model.

Is it nessecary to add the [Association("", "", "")] tags, when the model already contains this information due to its relations (foreign keys)?